# Ruby - URL encoding

Tags: ruby, url, urlencode, url-encoding

I have a URL string where there are line breaks and carriage returns. E.g.

```
http://xyz.com/hello?name=john&msg=hello\nJohn\n\rgoodmorning&note=last\night I went to \roger
```

Where my actual `msg` string is:

```
hello
john
goodmorning
```

and `note` string is

```
last\night I went to \roger
```

In order to send it correctly I have to urlencode this

```
 http://xyz.com/hello?name%3Djohn%26msg%3Dhello%5CnJohn%5Cn%5Crgoodmorning%26note%3Dlast%5Cnight%20I%20went%20to%20%5Croger
```

But this encode mess up \n and \r. While I expect \n should get converted to %0A and \r to %0D

I am writing code is ruby. And I tried to take help of `Addressable::URI` but no help yet. Other way could be replacing \n and \r manually to %0A and %0D respectively. But that replacement can replace valid character such as `last\night` to `last%0Aight` that I don't want. Can anyone suggest a better solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about [`CGI::escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape)

You need to only encode the parameters though.

```
url = "http://xyz.com/hello?"
params = "name=john&msg=hello\nJohn\n\rgoodmorning&note=last\night I went to \roger"

puts "#{url}#{CGI::escape(params)}"
# => "http://xyz.com/hello?name%3Djohn%26msg%3Dhello%0AJohn%0A%0Dgoodmorning%26note%3Dlast%0Aight+I+went+to+%0Doger"
```

Comment: I was thinking to write monkey patching `Class Hash def to_query
    self.map{|k,v| "#{CGI.escape(k)}=#{CGI.escape(v)}"}.join(“&”)
  end end` so that I can just use `hash.to_query` but it wont work becaus eof obvious reason "CGI" and throw error NameError: uninitialized constant Hash::CGI is there any way to solve that.

Comment: First of all, did not you see that `CGI` is also escaping the '&'s ? If you want to do something like this, you should also be sure that `k` and `v` are strings otherwise `CGI::escape` will raise an error. And finally, I had no problem testing it locally. You have a weird `"` in your `.join(“&”)` and you could try to add `::` in front of `CGI` as `::CGI`.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it using [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable):

```
require 'addressable/uri'

url = 'http://xyz.com/hello'

msg = 'hello
john
goodmorning'

note = "last\night I went to \roger"

uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)
uri.query_values = {
  'msg'  => msg,
  'note' => note
}

puts uri.to_s
```

Which returns:

```
http://xyz.com/hello?msg=hello%0Ajohn%0Agoodmorning&note=last%0Aight%20I%20went%20to%20%0Doger
```

The `\r` in `\roger` and `\n` in `\night` are converted because I used a double-quote delimited string, instead of a single-quote delimited string, which would have preserved `\r` and `\n` as literals.

Answer (score 1):

Passing json, quotes etc in GET request is tricky. In Ruby 2+ we can use Ruby's URI module's 'escape' method.

```
> URI.escape('http://app.com/method.json?agent={"account":
{"homePage":"http://demo.my.com","name":"Senior Leadership"}}')
```

But I suggest use it as POST request and pass it as a message body.